# The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I am trying to run my Next.js project in VSC. However, the terminal abruptly closes after a few minutes and gives the following error message.

[image]

I tried re-installing VSC but it didn't help. What should I do ? I am currently running Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have a perfect fix for the problem, but here's what you can do,

install Windows Terminal; a terminal emulator that you can get on the Microsoft store.

1. now instead of using the main terminal from the vs code, open up the windows terminal,

[Windows Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gmQj.png)

2. cd and paste the directory, (you can do it by dragging the folder)
   [entering directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46rsH.png)

and now you can access the terminal from here, and it won't shut down.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem by resetting my PC back to the original settings.

Comment: Any steps you could add to your answer for the next person who comes along?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).